# Bootstrap javascript functionalities are not working in my react project

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I was implementing a bootstrap `navbar` in my react project using the template provided in the bootstrap site. which is

```
 <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light'>
                    <div className='container-fluid'>
                        <a className='navbar-brand' href='#'>
                            Navbar
                        </a>
                        <button
                            className='navbar-toggler'
                            type='button'
                            data-bs-toggle='collapse'
                            data-bs-target='#navbarSupportedContent'
                            aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent'
                            aria-expanded='false'
                            aria-label='Toggle navigation'>
                            <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
                        </button>
                        <div className='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
                            <ul className='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0'>
                                <li className='nav-item'>
                                    <a className='nav-link active' aria-current='page' href='#'>
                                        Home
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li className='nav-item'>
                                    <a className='nav-link' href='#'>
                                        Link
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li className='nav-item dropdown'>
                                    <a
                                        className='nav-link dropdown-toggle'
                                        href='#'
                                        id='navbarDropdown'
                                        role='button'
                                        data-bs-toggle='dropdown'
                                        aria-expanded='false'>
                                        Dropdown
                                    </a>
                                    <ul className='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='navbarDropdown'>
                                        <li>
                                            <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>
                                                Action
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>
                                                Another action
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <hr className='dropdown-divider' />
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>
                                                Something else here
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li className='nav-item'>
                                    <a
                                        className='nav-link disabled'
                                        href='#'
                                        tabindex='-1'
                                        aria-disabled='true'>
                                        Disabled
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <form className='d-flex'>
                                <input
                                    className='form-control me-2'
                                    type='search'
                                    placeholder='Search'
                                    aria-label='Search'
                                />
                                <button className='btn btn-outline-success' type='submit'>
                                    Search
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

I replaced `class` with `className`

then,first I installed bootstrap with `npm i bootstrap`
and imported bootstrap using `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";` on `index.js` file.
at this point, all bootstrap styles were working but, when I click on dropdown menu, it's not working.
after some search on internet I found a video demonstrating how to implement bootsrap navbar.
[youtube video implementing bootstrap navbar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZuf4E4z4sk)
then realised I have to install `jquery` as well
and then I installed `jquery` with `npm i jquery`. and imported using `import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";` on `index.js`
unfortunately it didn't work.
This is my package.json depandancies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `react-bootstrap` or `reactstrap` to clean jquery and handle logic with reactDOM.